# Preferred DOM library for parsing html pages with node.js?

Tags: dom, node.js

I'm looking for libraries that parse html pages ( with some leniency, not strict xml parsers ). Can anyone recommend any?

Edit: Came across [jsdom](http://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently heard about jsdom via [Video: Elijah Insua — jsdom: a CommonJS Implementation of the DOM](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/video.php?v=insua-dom) from the Yahoo Developer Network.